# How to deal with mixed line endings in Git?

Tags: customlabel, git

This problem only occurs if you version non-code in a Git repository. It happens with most non-code but I will use custom labels as an example. So, let's assume we have a custom label called `NewLine` (for use in some formula fields, etc. - it's a common hack) that features two dashes with a `CRLF` in between.

This is how it looks in the XML file when pulled from Salesforce:

```
    <labels>
        <fullName>NewLine</fullName>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>NewLine</shortDescription>
        <value>-
-</value>
    </labels>
```

Salesforce uses `LF` throughout all files as a line ending - just the line with the `<value>` tag will end with the `CRLF` that is used in the value of the custom label. So the question is - how do I handle these exceptions within Git? I cannot use `eol=lf` in my `.gitattributes` for normalization, but making an exception with `-eol` increases the likelihood of screwing this up locally, committing it back to the repository, and potentially deploying this to production, screwing up places where this custom label is used. This is just an example as this problem happens to me everywhere - translations, flow, etc., or custom labels as in this example.

Any ideas on how to deal with this? Surely I'm not the only one affected by this.

Comment: The answer to this question would depend on how you interface with git. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944243/does-git-internally-store-line-endings

Comment: @identigral Since data is stored as a blob and no conversion takes place one could argue that this is already what I need. But I'm not satisfied with this answer as it still allows users to screw this up.